# Timer enables, when it should not in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview, timer

With a button click i'm trying to check existing rows in the listview.

```
  Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
    Button8.Click
 If ListViewExtended1.Items.Count >= 0 Then
    timer_firstROW.Enabled = True
 Else
    timer_firstROW.Enabled = False
End If
If ListViewExtended1.Items.Count >= 1 Then
    timer_SecondRow.Enabled = True
Else
    timer_SecondRow.Enabled = False
End If
If ListViewExtended1.Items.Count >= 2 Then
    Timer_ThirdRow.Enabled = True
Else
    Timer_ThirdRow.Enabled = False
End If
End Sub
```

the problem is that i got an invalid argument exception = 1 in timer's sub

```
  Private Sub timer_SecondRow_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
    timer_SecondRow.Tick
    timer_SecondRow.Interval = ListViewExtended1.Items(1).SubItems(3).Text
 End Sub
```

all timers a disabled by default, so when we a checking if else statements and have only 1 item with index 0 in listview, i got that exception, it means that timer enabled, but why..

I tried to make code that, will check existing rows in listview, if row exist, timer will be enabled then timer will send continous messages thourgh serial. if 3 rows existing, 3 rows timers will be enabled and send messages with an interval will assign with "ListViewExtended1.Items(1).SubItems(3).Text". COde of timers:

```
  Private Sub Timer4_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
 timer_firstROW.Tick
    timer_firstROW.Interval = ListViewExtended1.Items(0).SubItems(3).Text
    count_for_rx = ListViewExtended1.Items(0).SubItems(4).Text + 1
    ListViewExtended1.Items(0).SubItems(4).Text = count_for_rx
    GetValueFromlv2Row = "434D4431" & ListViewExtended1.Items(0).SubItems(0).Text & ListViewExtended1.Items(0).SubItems(1).Text & ListViewExtended1.Items(0).SubItems(2).Text.Replace(" ", "")
    Dim count As Short
    Dim bytestosend(0) As Byte
    For count = 1 To GetValueFromlv2Row.Length Step 2  'For count = 249 To Text4.Text * 2 Step 8 page 32
        bytestosend(0) = CLng("&H" & Mid(GetValueFromlv2Row, count, 2))
        spObj.Write(bytestosend, 0, bytestosend.Length)
    Next
    spObj.Write(Microsoft.VisualBasic.ControlChars.Cr)
End Sub

     Private Sub timer_SecondRow_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
  Handles timer_SecondRow.Tick
    If Not ListViewExtended1.Items(1).ToString() = "" Then
        timer_SecondRow.Interval = 
    ListViewExtended1.Items(1).SubItems(3).Text
        count_for_rx = ListViewExtended1.Items(1).SubItems(4).Text + 1
        ListViewExtended1.Items(1).SubItems(4).Text = count_for_rx
        GetValueFromlv2Row = "434D4431" & 
     ListViewExtended1.Items(1).SubItems(0).Text & 
    ListViewExtended1.Items(1).SubItems(1).Text & 
    ListViewExtended1.Items(1).SubItems(2).Text.Replace(" ", "")
        Dim count As Short
        Dim bytestosend(0) As Byte
        For count = 1 To GetValueFromlv2Row.Length Step 2  'For count = 249 
    To Text4.Text * 2 Step 8 page 32
            bytestosend(0) = CLng("&H" & Mid(GetValueFromlv2Row, count, 2))
            spObj.Write(bytestosend, 0, bytestosend.Length)
        Next
        spObj.Write(Microsoft.VisualBasic.ControlChars.Cr)
    Else
        timer_SecondRow.Enabled = False
    End If
 End Sub
 Private Sub Timer_ThirdRow_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
Timer_ThirdRow.Tick
    Timer_ThirdRow.Interval = ListViewExtended1.Items(2).SubItems(3).Text
    count_for_rx = ListViewExtended1.Items(2).SubItems(4).Text + 1
    ListViewExtended1.Items(2).SubItems(4).Text = count_for_rx
    GetValueFromlv2Row = "434D4431" & 
  ListViewExtended1.Items(2).SubItems(0).Text & 
 ListViewExtended1.Items(2).SubItems(1).Text & 
ListViewExtended1.Items(2).SubItems(2).Text.Replace(" ", "")
    Dim count As Short
    Dim bytestosend(0) As Byte
    For count = 1 To GetValueFromlv2Row.Length Step 2  'For count = 249 To 
 Text4.Text * 2 Step 8 page 32
        bytestosend(0) = CLng("&H" & Mid(GetValueFromlv2Row, count, 2))
        spObj.Write(bytestosend, 0, bytestosend.Length)
    Next
    spObj.Write(Microsoft.VisualBasic.ControlChars.Cr)
End Sub
```

Comment: Putting this code in a button's Click event handler is not sensible.  It needs to be located in the code that adds or removes items from the ListView.

Comment: To follow your code.. If the item count = 0, timer_firstRow will be enabled and the other two will be disabled. If the item count <0(impossible) all timers  will be disabled. If the item count =1, then timer_firstRow will be enabled because of the first If statement will be true, and timer_secondRow will be enabled and timer_thirdRow will be disabled. If the item count =3 then all three timers will be enabled. If the item count is >3 then all three timers will be enabled. Are you sure that this is the logic you want?

Comment: Once timer_firstRow is enabled, your code as it stands will never disable it. and you will always have at least one of the other timers enabled.

Comment: @DavidWilson after your explanation, seems it not the logic i need. But how to check existing rows in listview and depends on it - enabling timers?

Comment: I think that it would be helpful if you could give a more complete description of what you want your code to do, and edit your question to include the code that in the timers as well. Thanks

Comment: @DavidWilson Sry, you are right. Edited